# What's the proper term for pronunciation marks (or is that it)?

Tags: pronunciation

Never heard an official term for the marks used to describe pronunciation - the various lines, carets, accent marks, etc used in the written out version, as in "prə-nŭn′sē-ā′shən"

"Pronunciation marks" seems a logical guess, as in punctuation marks, but I've no idea if there's a more proper and fancy term for them.

Collectively, that is - I'm sure each circumflex and caret has their own name when used as such. That'd be another question.

Answer (score 1):

The word you seem to be looking for is [***diacritic***](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/diacritic) (link to dictionary.com), or ***diacritical mark***. This refers specifically to the accent-like marks that are placed over the letters as in your example; if you were also interested in including in the class letter-like symbols such as the schwa [ə], or the symbols of the [International Phonetic Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet), I would suggest the “class name” of ***phonetic symbols***.

Comment: I doubt if we can mix up diacritical marks with the (same) symbols used to indicate pronunciation. They are functionally different.

Comment: @Kris - how so? Both are used to indicate changes in pronunciation as compared to the unmarked letter. The definition does not specify a _reason_ for applying the marks, nor does it specify what any particular mark means (and the meaning may change depending on context; an acute accent in French means something different than an acute accent in Spanish).